# Alex FTPS getting callback from PutFile

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm currently using Alex FTPS to upload a file. However I would like to get the result message from the putfile command.

I see there is a filetransfercallback but I don't know how to use that exactly.

```
using (FTPSClient client = new FTPSClient())
            {
                // connect to the server
                client.Connect(FTPServer, new NetworkCredential(FTPUser, FTPPwd),
                           ESSLSupportMode.CredentialsRequired | ESSLSupportMode.DataChannelRequested | ESSLSupportMode.Implicit, 
                           new RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(ValidateTestServerCertificate) );
                client.SetTransferMode(ETransferMode.Binary);

                // upload the file
                myResult += client.PutFile(FileName, fi.Name, filetransfercallback???);
            }
```

How do I get the info from the filetransfercallback?

Comment: Look at the [discussion](https://ftps.codeplex.com/discussions/207439) from the Alex FTPS website and see if that helps.

Comment: It helps slightly. but not by much.

Comment: using the code on that page. It makes a function that's a static void. but I want it to return a string that I can display. however changing the declaration to static string throws an error that the transfercallback has the wrong return type.

Comment: Yeah it is using the Console to write out messages.  Look at the [full source](https://ftps.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#FTPSClient/FTPSClientCmdApp/Program.cs)  of the Program.cs file.

Comment: Curious, What kind of info are you looking to return?

Comment: I'd like to know the status. Whether success, waiting, uploading or complete.